# Trying to return the middle value in an arraylist of strings

Tags: java, processing

Trying to write a function called `F2` that should take in an `ArrayList` of `Strings` called words as a
parameter, and return the middle value in the list. If the middle item is a fraction (list
size 7) then return the rounded down item (3).

code i've written so far: seems to be incorrect what am i missing

```
public String F2 ( ArrayList<String> words ) 
{
    return words.get(2); 
}
```

Comment: What you have written simply returns the 3rd element of the array.  You need to compute the offset of the middle element, then get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be getting the middle element, you current *always* get the **third** element. Also, your method could be `static` (and you ***could*** make it **generic**). And prefer the `List` interface to the concrete `ArrayList` type. Like,

```
public static <T> T F2(List<T> words) {
    return words.get(words.size() / 2);
}
```